# scraping craigslist results "Page not found" using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I tried to fetch the contents of CL page and display it as a separate html page using python's BeautifulSoup.

But it results in "page not found".

```
d={'query':'doctor'}
encoder=urllib.urlencode(d).encode('ASCII')
page1=urllib.urlopen('chennai.craigslist.co.in/search',encoder)
content=page1.read()
file1=open("r.html",'w')
file1.write(content.decode())
```

Comment: You will have to show some code

Comment: d={'query':'doctor'}
encoder=urllib.urlencode(d).encode('ASCII')
page1=urllib.urlopen('http://chennai.craigslist.co.in/search',encoder)
content=page1.read()

file1=open("r.html",'w')
file1.write(content.decode())

Comment: ^ Please edit your (formatted) code into the question, thanks.

Comment: i added value "jjj" which denotes  "job". but still it is not working. page1=urllib.urlopen('chennai.craigslist.co.in/search/jjj',encoder)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code works in python version 3.. Thanks for the contributions.